# C# convert System.Func<Tderived, bool> to System/Func<Tbase, bool>

Tags: c#, linq, func, derived

I've googled but couldn't find satisfactory answers. I'm basically trying to get this code to work:

```
public List<WordEntry> WordDataBase = new List<WordEntry>();
public List<CharacterEntry> CharacterDataBase = new List<CharacterEntry>();

public List<Entry> SelectWhere<T>(System.Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : Entry
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(WordEntry))
        return WordDataBase.Where(predicate);
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(CharacterEntry))
        return CharacterDataBase.Where(predicate);
    else
        return null;
}
```

In this sample, both WordEntry and CharacterEntry are derived from Entry. I get the compiler errors:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Func<T, bool>' to 'System.Func<WordEntry, int, bool>'
```

and

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Func<T, bool>' to 'System.Func<CharacterEntry, int, bool>'
```

Hopefully you can help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that this is slightly pointless as a method. If you have 2 types, then have two methods.

Comment: If you're doing type checking on a generic type then you've almost always made a poor design choice.

Comment: I would say it has something to do with type variance - the compiler won't allow implicit cast to a parent type.

Comment: Okay thanks for answering everybody. But I see a lot of people replying to the specific function I wrote. However, this function is just a basic version of what I'm trying to achieve. In the final version I want to setup a much more complex and dynamic system based on the casting of the func. So everybody can ignore the function with the if/else statement and only utilizing two types. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Basically, you just need to cast - the language rules don't allow the compiler to take the `if` statement into account when it thinks about the types involved. Note that you *also* need to call `ToList<Entry>()`, specifying the type argument to avoid getting a `List<WordEntry>` or `List<CharacterEntry>`:

```
public List<Entry> SelectWhere<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : Entry
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(WordEntry))
        return WordDataBase
            .Where((Func<WordEntry, bool>) predicate)
            .ToList<Entry>();
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(CharacterEntry))
        return CharacterDataBase
            .Where((Func<CharacterEntry, bool>) predicate)
            .ToList<Entry>();
    else
        return null;
}
```

I'd suggest that rather than making this generic though, you might want to just have two different methods instead. It doesn't feel like it's *really* a generic method, given that it only works with two very specific types.

Comment: Thank you for answering. However I tried casting the func before. But the part:
    (Func<WordEntry, bool>)predicate
Gives the error:
    Error CS0030 Cannot convert type 'System.Func<T, bool>' to 'System.Func<WordEntry, bool>'

Comment: @user1370286: Ah, you may need a cast to `object` first. Will add that in.

Comment: @user1370286: Actually, no, my code compiles fine for me. It really should be fine - will create a gist to show...

Comment: @user1370286: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/1c63090d847a97cc757352807cfc0a50 compiles with no errors.

Answer (score 4):

Your method `SelectWhere` does different things based on the type of argument - so why not just use overload methods

```
public List<WordEntry> SelectWhere(Func<WordEntry, bool> predicate)
{
    return WordDataBase.Where(predicate);
} 

public List<CharacterEntry> SelectWhere(Func<CharacterEntry, bool> predicate)
{
    return CharacterDataBase.Where(predicate);
}
```

Then you can use those method without casting and "horrible" `if...else` statements

```
Func<WordEntry, bool> isValid = word => word.SomeProperty > 0;
var filteredWords = SelectWhere(isValid); // WordDataBase will be used

Func<CharacterEntry, bool> IsValid = character => character.SomeProperty != null;
var filteredCharacters = SelectWhere(IsValid); //CharacterDataBase will be used
```

Answer (score 0):

From the errors you have shown i think your predicate has wrong declaration.

The where clause on both of your **Database** objects expects `Func<T, int, bool>`, note the second argument which is **int**, so changing your extension method like this should be progress in the right direction

```
public List<Entry> SelectWhere<T>(Func<T, int, bool> predicate) where T : Entry
```

NOTE: You have declared generic method in which your code depends on the generic type, this makes to code somehow not so generic, check @Fabio answer i think he has point for creating the separate extension methods.